# Clicking on a specific child of a ListView in Espresso

Tags: android-espresso

Using Espresso, I'd like to be able to click on a specific child of an ExpandableListView (named CustomExpandableView).  The listview creates a set of RelativeLayouts (named MyContainer).

Ideally, I'd like to click on a specific MyContainer in CustomExpandableView.  But, I can live with just clicking the very first one.

The MyContainer objects do not have unique IDs I can reference, but their children do, e.g. - "text=Sample Text Here 1"

I have tried a few different variations of using onData passing the class type and trying to get a child at a specific position, but its just not working.  And, I wanted to avoid getting the object and iterating over it until I found the right child.

Here is the portion of the view hierarchy for reference (I removed non-important info from the hierarchy):

```
+----->CustomExpandableView{} 
|
+------>LinearLayout{}
|
+------->TextView{}
|
+------->FrameLayout{}
|
+-------->BreadCrumbView{}
|
+--------->ImageButton{}
|
+--------->TextView{}
|
+------>LinearLayout{}
|
+------->MyContainer{}
|
+-------->ImageView{res-name=thumb, }
|
+-------->ImageView{res-name=divider}
|
+-------->TextView{res-name=label, text=Sample Text Here 1, input-type=0, ime-target=false}
|
+------->MyContainer{}
|
+-------->ImageView{res-name=thumb}
|
+-------->ImageView{res-name=divider}
|
+-------->TextView{res-name=label text=Sample Text Here 2, input-type=0, ime-target=false}
|
```

Answer (score 1):

When you trying to use `onData`, Espresso tries to find not view by some params, but get `Adapter` of `ListView` and search for data in this adapter(by calling `Adapter#getItem`).

But in the case of `ExpandableListView` it is not obvious what data to get.
And for this purpose Espresso provided `onData...().usingAdapterViewProtocol(AdapterViewProtocol)`. This method javadoc says:

`/**
   * Use a different AdapterViewProtocol if the Adapter implementation does not
   * satisfy the AdapterView contract like (@code ExpandableListView)
   */`

This AdapterViewProtocol interface looks like : http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/5.0.0_r1/com/google/android/apps/common/testing/ui/espresso/action/AdapterViewProtocol.java .

Examples of `AdapterViewProtocol` implementation : https://stackoverflow.com/a/40282991/1282732

After correctly defining it, `onData` will find item view you searched for. After that, if you need to perform an action or check on the child. You just should `onData#onChildView`.

Answer (score 0):

Try the instanceOf coupled with a `hasSibling` matcher e.g.

```
onView(allOf(is(instanceOf(MyContainer.class)), hasSibling(withText("Sample Text Here 1"))))
```

Comment: This is returning error. OnView requires Matcher<View> and this is returning Matcher<Object>. You have not specified any view object in OnView.

Comment: @Khushboo, so switch it to onData.

Answer (score 0):

You can follow provided directly by Google here [EspressoSamples](https://code.google.com/p/android-test-kit/wiki/EspressoSamples#Matching_data_using_onData_and_a_custom_ViewMatcher).
You have to use  `onData()` as e.g.

```
onData(allOf(is(instanceOf(Map.class)), hasEntry(equalTo("STR"), is("item: 50")))
  .perform(click());
```

Answer (score 0):

```
val listViewItem = onData(anything()).inAdapterView(withId(android.R.id.list)).atPosition(10)

listViewItem.onChildView(withId(android.R.id.checkbox)).check(matches(isChecked()))
```

This will be helpful, if you know the position of the view where you need to access the child.
Here, in the first line, I got the 10th position view(i.e.viewgroup) from the list view.
In the second line I access its child 'checkbox' and asserting on it. FYI:This is in kotlin and you can convert the same to java using android studio.