# How to use AdapterViewProtocol in espresso?

Tags: android, testing, implementation, android-espresso

I use Espresso 2.0 library to test an Android project, and I need to use method `onData`, but I have custom ProductsAdapter, so I must implement AdapterViewProtocol (`android.support.test.espresso.action.AdapterViewProtocol`),

I need to find a working example implementing AdapterViewProtocol for `onData` method.

I have only found this: https://gist.github.com/brennantaylor/9379399. But I want  small and working project. Help me, please.

Comment: You don't need to implement AdapterViewProtocol, as long as your adapter doesn't break the basic protocol. So first try without, else add more detail. As it stands the question is impossible to answer.

Comment: my adapter break the basic protocol, so I need to implement AdapterViewProtocol.

Comment: @Julia did you find anything regarding to this issue?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to look at this example with CursorAdapter:
https://gist.github.com/brennantaylor/9379399 .

Or in standard Espresso implementation:
http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/5.0.0_r1/com/google/android/apps/common/testing/ui/espresso/action/AdapterViewProtocols.java#AdapterViewProtocols.StandardAdapterViewProtocol